# Premiere Pro - How to pan around zoomed in Program Monitor

Tags: premiere, keyboard-shortcut

I can't seem to find an answer to this anyplace online.

When I zoom in on the Program Monitor window, there is no way for me to easily pan around the window:

[image]

In other Adobe programs, you hold <kbd>Space</kbd> and drag with a mouse or even just slide a finger along the Magic Mouse to change which area you're zoomed in on.

Is there something like this in Premiere?  It's driving me nuts having to use the scroll bars manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

Press <kbd>H</kbd> to switch to the Hand Tool, then you can drag the viewport around

Comment: I love that Premiere gives me job security. Once I figure stuff like this out, I take the PR oath not to share the information.    :).  Seriously though, this is so non-intuitive.  That, and to go back to non H mode, you need to press the pointer in the toolbar (instead of the hand)